# 2 pieces of similar PHP, one works one doesn't?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I've got a few fields on a property site, grabbing a value in English & depending on the value, translating it (if another language other than English is selected).

This piece of code works fine:

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'prop_parking',true) && $prop_parking):
    $prop_parking_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'prop_parking',true);
    if ($prop_parking_meta == 'Yes') {
        $prop_parking_meta = '<!--:en-->Yes<!--:--><!--:es-->Sí<!--:--><!--:ru-->да<!--:-->';
    }
    elseif ($prop_parking_meta == 'No') {
        $prop_parking_meta = '<!--:en-->No<!--:--><!--:es-->No<!--:--><!--:ru-->нет<!--:-->';
    } ?> 
         <li>
           <p><?php echo PROP_PARK_CSTM;?>:</p><p> <?php _e( $prop_parking_meta ); ?></p>
         </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I get back `Yes`in the set language, yet in this field I don't (I just see `Yes` or `No`):

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'prop_garage',true) && $prop_garage):
    $prop_garage_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'prop_garage',true);
    if ($prop_garage_meta == 'Yes') {
        $prop_garage_meta = '<!--:en-->Yes<!--:--><!--:es-->Sí<!--:--><!--:ru-->да<!--:-->';
    }
    elseif ($prop_garage_meta == 'No') {
        $prop_garage_meta = '<!--:en-->No<!--:--><!--:es-->No<!--:--><!--:ru-->нет<!--:-->';
    } ?>        
          <li>
           <p><?php echo PROP_GARG_CSTM;?>:</p><p> <?php _e( $prop_garage_meta ); ?></p>
          </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is it something obvious I'm missing? :( Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that `$prop_garage_meta` is not 'Yes' when selecting a different language.

Comment: How are the values saved to the metadata table?

Comment: Are both scripts running in the same theme template?

Comment: @brasofilo Yes, both are in same template, there are others too.

Comment: @Daan It is `yes`, yet when I change language of page it always stays as yes (not showing Spanish & Russian translations of `Yes`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this issue happens sometimes in qTranslate, but there are two options to deal with it:

1. using the shortcode notation

   ```
   $prop_garage_meta = '[:en]Yes[:es]Sí[:ru]да';
   ```
2. applying `the_content` filter

   ```
   $prop_garage_meta = apply_filters( 
       'the_content', 
       '<!--:en-->Yes<!--:--><!--:es-->Sí<!--:--><!--:ru-->да<!--:-->' 
   );
   ```